# How to format the case equation to look nicer?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, fontsize

I want to typeset the equation in my beamer frame:
[image]

This is my solution and of course, it doesn't look well.

[image]

And my code is :

```
\[
    \parbox[c][2cm]{2cm}{Attainable \\ GFlops/sec} = \min{\begin{cases} 
                 \parbox[c][1cm]{3cm}{\small Peak Floating\-Point \\ Performance} \\
                 \hrulefill \\ 
                 \parbox[c][1cm]{2.5cm}{\small Peak Memory\\ Bandwidth }
                 \times 
                 \parbox[c][1cm]{2.5cm}{\small Operational \\ Intensity} \end{cases}}
  \]
```

The question: How can I typeset it to make it looks like the first picture? I use `\parbox` to break the operand, but they isn't aligned at center. I use `\small`, but the right operands of the equation is still the same size of the left operand.

Comment: The brace suggests a choice (the minimum) between two options while the line between these two options suggests a fraction: your formula is ambiguous.

Comment: @PaulGaborit：Yes. The line between them is used to distinguish the top and bottom (not necessary). If deleting the line, the right seems to be one equation. And this equation comes from the paper I read, so I just keep it same as the paper.

Comment: Notice that 'min' *should* not be in italics, just as 'sin' shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack it!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\stacktype{L}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here is the equation:\bigskip

{\rmfamily$\stackanchor{Attainable}{GFlops/sec} = \textit{min}
\left\{
  \footnotesize\frac{
    \stackanchor{Peak Floating-Point}{Performance}
  }{
    \stackanchor{Peak Memory}{Bandwidth} ~~\times~~
    \stackanchor{Operational}{Intensity}
  }
\right.
$}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

While it produces the identical result, some may prefer the following stacking syntax.  It replaces `\stackanchor{...}{...}` with `\Centerstack{...\\...}`.  Also, it eliminates the need for `\def\stacktype{L}` and `\strutlongstacks{T}`, since a `\Centerstack` is always a "long", strutted stack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here is the equation:\bigskip

{\rmfamily$\Centerstack{Attainable\\GFlops/sec} = \textit{min}
\left\{
  \footnotesize\frac{
    \Centerstack{Peak Floating-Point\\Performance}
  }{
    \Centerstack{Peak Memory\\Bandwidth} ~~\times~~
    \Centerstack{Operational\\Intensity}
  }
\right.
$}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually, 'min' is not written in italics since it is an operator.

Comment: @Karlo I agree (`$\min$` would be preferable), but the italic matches the stated desires of the OP, so I gave what was requested.

Answer (score 6):

My own attempt, using a combination of `tabular` and `dcases` environments, and `\frac` and `\times` operators. I wanted to use as much arithmetic operators as possible. Maybe it wasn't the right tactic but in the end it doesn't look so bad, I think.

Edit: added `@{}` in argument of the first `tabular` environment, to suppress an ugly additional space. (Idea taken from Gonzalo Medina's answer.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
  \begin{tabular}{c@{}}Attainable\\ GFlops/sec\end{tabular}
  = \min
  \left\lbrace
    \frac{
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        Peak Floating-Point\\ Performance
      \end{tabular}
      }
      {
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        Peak Memory\\ Bandwidth
      \end{tabular}
      \times
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        Operational\\ Intensity
      \end{tabular}
      }
  \right.
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit (bis): following egreg's remarks in the comments, I've replaced the `dcases` environment by `\left\lbrace…\right.` instructions, and taken off some spurious `\text` instructions. Simpler code thus, and the new result seems exactly the same as the old one but I've uploaded it anyway.

Comment: I'd use `\left\lbrace` instead of `\begin{dcases}` and `\right.` instead of `\end{dcases}`. Or no brace at all, but it's another matter. Why `$\text{GFlops}/\text{sec}$` and not simply `GFlops/sec`?

Comment: The `\text{}` commands are relics of previous attempts: I first wanted to remain in math mode (`array` environments) as much as possible. Indeed you're right, the `\left…\right` approach is better and simpler. I've modified my code accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, using `tabular` and `array`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

{
\small
\[
\begin{tabular}{c@{}}
Attainable \\ 
GFlops/sec 
\end{tabular}
= \min
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Peak Floating\-Point \\ 
  Performance
\end{tabular} \\
\midrule
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.2cm}@{}}
  Peak Memory \\ 
  Bandwidth 
\end{tabular}
\times 
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}@{}}
  Operational \\ 
  Intensity
\end{tabular} 
\end{array}
\right.
\]
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A `varwidth` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
  \centering Attainable \\ GFlops/sec
  \end{varwidth}
  =\min\begin{cases}
  \frac{
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \small\centering Peak Floating Point \\ Performance \rule[-2pt]{0pt}{1pt}

    \end{varwidth}
  }
  {
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \small\centering Peak Memory\\ Bandwidth 
    \end{varwidth}
    \,\, \times \,\,
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \small\centering \rule{0pt}{2ex} Operational \\ Intensity
    \end{varwidth}
  }
  \end{cases}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

And TikZ, of course.

## Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mybox[1]{
  \tikz[baseline=-.5ex]
  \node[align=center,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{2.5ex},text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
  \mybox{Attainable\\GFlops/sec}=\min
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{\mybox{Peak Floating Point\\Performance}}
    {\mybox{Peak Memory\\Bandwidth}\times\mybox{Operational\\Intensity}}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]